# Reduce duplicated boilerplate code in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, architecture

I'm quite new to React and I don't know if there is a pattern to reduce duplicated code. I'm aware of higher order components but I'm not sure how/if they can help me. Here is the issue that I'm having:

Here is the scenario:

I have three React components in my app: Studios, Projects, Actors

Each component corresponds to a route on the front-end:

- /projects: `Projects`
- /studios: `Studios`
- /actors: `Actors`

Each component does pretty much the same thing, looping through the items and render a component:

- Projects: loop through the data for projects and render a `Project` component for each project
- Studios: loop through the data for studios and render a `Studio` component for each studio
- Actors: loop through the data for actors and render an `Actor` component for each actor

Now the model for a `Project`, `Studio`, and `Actor` are pretty much the same with slight variation:

- `Studio`: image, name, details
- `Actor`:  image, name, and bio
- `Project`:image, title, and description

Also, on the "List" view, when I click on an item, it takes me to the details of that item. For example, when I am on the `/projects` view when I click on a project item, it takes me to `/projects/:id` and renders the `ProjectDetail` component. So by now for each entity I have three components: `ItemList`, `Item`, `ItemDetail`. Which is total of 3 x 3 = 9 components. I feel like there is a better way of doing this. Maybe I don't understand the responsibility of the router? Right now, I have a route for the `ItemList` and `ItemDetail` for every entity:

- /projects: `Projects`
- /projects/:id: `ProjectDetail`

---

- /actors: `Actors`
- /actors/id: `ActorDetail`

---

- /studios: `Studios`
- /studios/:id: `StudioDetail`

Eventually I would like to generalize models that are very similar to each other to reduce boilerplate code. Possibly:

- `ItemList`: would take `data` as an input and render the appropriate `Item` component.
- `Item`: The component that would show up on the `ItemList`
- `ItemDetail`: The component that shows the details of the `Item`

and a generic client route rule that can automatically map the route to the appropriate component.

Comment: Could you provide a little more detail? It sounds like you're describing React's most basic scenario of components and children components but it's hard to tell. FWIW, `props.children` is nothing more than the children passed to a component: `<MyComponent><h1>TEST</h1></MyComponent>` is the same as `<MyComponent children={<h1>Test</h1>} />`

Comment: Much better! Alright so have have you tried? There is a technique I've been meaning to write about somewhere that could help in your case but I want to make sure it's what you're after before proposing it as an answer. In short, would you be able to provide all the information you need to a generic component using a single json file as configuration? Think you can pass anything that's json serializable along like titles, name of component, links, etc.

Comment: @ZekeDroid no I haven't tried that. I'm also looking into Router5, there are some interesting concepts there, but I'm not sure if it will help me generalize my resources/components/routes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to refer to **components** vs **instances** in my answer; check out [this article](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html) for an explanation of the differences, or read this **TL;DR**: a component is the *class or function* that specifies the behavior of a JSX tag, while an instance is typically represented by JSX in a `render` method. So `function Foo() { return <div />;}` would be a *component*, while `<Foo />` would be an *instance*.

The magic of JSX is that *tag names are simply variables*. For instance, when you type `<div />`, the tag name is simply referring to a `div` variable defined by React core. Assuming you've imported a component `Foo`, when you type `<Foo />` then the tag name is referring to the variable you've brought in scope by importing.

You could use a higher-order component that takes a React component, and then use that component in the render method. For example *(disclaimer, I'm writing this on-the-fly and it may contain errors)*:

```
// Assume the variables `studios, actors, projects` are arrays
// of their respective item types, and `StudioDetail, ActorDetail,
// ProjectDetail` are the customized views you've described in
// your question.

class ItemList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const View = this.props.view;
    const items = this.props.items;
    return (<div>
      {items.map((item, i) => <View key={i} item={item} />}
    </div>);
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<div>
      <ItemList view={StudioDetail} items={studios} />
      <ItemList view={ActorDetail} items={actors} />
      <ItemList view={ProjectDetail} items={projects} />
    </div>);
  }
}
```

Just make sure that whatever you pass into the `view` prop is a component matching the type of item you're showing, and you ought to be off to a good start.